# Main process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING

Tags: service, node.js, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, systemctl

I have a node application, running via a systemd service on Ubuntu 16.04

However, after some time the service is getting restarted automatically.

Here's what I get in the logs:

```
Mar 17 14:35:10 testmachine systemd[1]: myService.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING
Mar 17 14:35:10 testmachine systemd[1]: myService.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 17 14:35:10 testmachine systemd[1]: myService.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 17 14:35:40 testmachine systemd[1]: myService.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
```

From what I understand, the systemd detects that the service is not running and restarts is after 30 seconds, as I have specified in the service config file.

**myService.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=The will start node app
After=cleanMongo.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/media/path/to/execution/scriptFile
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But my issue is, why does it think the service is not running? The application is doing its thing and in the middle it restarts.

**PS:** I have lots of CRON jobs running in the node application, is it the case that the process is too busy to reply to some kind of `isAlive` from the systemd? And thats why systemd thinks its not running?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, systemd/systemctl would report the failure to start (if/when you run `sudo systemctl start myService.service`).

I would check:

- the output of `sudo systemctl status myService.service`
- the output of `sudo journalctl -ln 2000 -u myService`

The output of either may help diagnose the issue (journalctl may be the better bet).

Also worth trying is replicating what your systemd service unit is doing - i.e. trying to run the same command from an interactive session (potentially using sudo) and seeing what errors are reported.

systemd/systemctl actually tracks the PID, so polling should not be an issue.

**Updated** based on your service definition, running the wrapper script could be one part of the issue.

Your systemd config expects to be able to track the process itself by PID. However, it would 'see' the PID of the script, but, depending on how you run node from that script, it may not be able to track node's PID.

It seems a more solid approach would be to run node directly (as suggested [here](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/)):

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Example Server
#Requires=After=mysql.service       # Requires the mysql service to run first

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /opt/nodeserver/server.js
#WorkingDirectory=/opt/nodeserver   # Required on some systems
Restart=always
RestartSec=10                       # Restart service after 10 seconds if node service crashes
StandardOutput=syslog               # Output to syslog
StandardError=syslog                # Output to syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-example
#User=<alternate user>
#Group=<alternate group>
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=1337

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This way, systemd is able to track the correct PID.

If you need to run some commands before running node, consider using systemd's `ExecStartPre`.

There are a number of other options systemd provides (see the [unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) man page), that may enable you to avoid using a wrapper:

- as mentionned, `ExecStartPre` allows you to perform tasks before the main process is started (and `ExecStartPost` to perform tasks after)
- you can express dependencies to other services via `Require`, `Wants`, `Before`, and `After`, and you can also use `Conflicts` or various `Condition*` keywords.

Comment: The messages I posted ARE output of `journalctl`. Before that it just had my application logs, executing cron jobs, etc

Comment: I wanted to move to the approach you posted, but there were a couple of other tasks in my script file. Like disabling another service first, then starting my application

Comment: The `WorkingDirectory` is not working for me. I have used `path.resolve()` at some places for config files which are in a the root of my project directory. But its not able to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm not a nodejs expert.

As others said you should move as most as possible into the systemd unit. The `cd` could be replaced by `WorkingDirectory` the sudo is useless but could be replaced by `User` and the environment variable could be set by `Environment`.

Systemd don't await any "isAlive" call from your daemon if `Type` is != `notify` (default is `simple`)

The `NOTRUNNING` is a interpretation of the exitcode of your process, this means your node process exits with errorcode 7 [Node Doc](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/doc/api/process.markdown#exit-codes) says the exit code means *"There was an uncaught exception, and the internal fatal exception handler function itself threw an error while attempting to handle it."* so there should some output in the journal or the log destination of nodejs.